# Survey-package: How do I get R-squared from a svyglm-object?

Tags: r, regression, survey, stargazer

I'm analysing a social survey and need to use `survey` package to account for oversampling. I performed a log-linear regression with `svyglm` command and everything worked perfectly fine. However, the output is an `svyglm` object that apparently does not include the R-squared value unlike normal `lm` objects. So how do I get this value and how do I include it in my regression table if its not part of the actual object? (I'm using `stargazer` package to create the tables for my paper)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's no R-squared for GLM's, report AIC/BIC instead. Also read: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3559/which-pseudo-r2-measure-is-the-one-to-report-for-logistic-regression-cox-s

Comment: You can also use pseudo R-squared measures for GLM https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11676/pseudo-r-squared-formula-for-glms

Comment: Question is probably insanely stupid, but why is there no R-squared for GLM?

@GRowInG I tried to calculate pseudo R-squared with `psrsq` but it says "Only implemented for discrete data"..

Comment: That question is not stupid at all, have a look at the first answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541899/why-doesnt-statsmodels-glm-have-r2-in-results

Comment: €GRowInG Thanks for the link. But do you have any idea, how I can calculate pseudo R-squared? I'm getting the error "Only implemented for discrete data", since apparently `psrsq()` only works with binomial or poisson models, according to this link: https://rdrr.io/cran/survey/src/R/rsquared.R

Answer (score 1):

If you have a linear regression model with `svyglm` you can get the residual variance and the total variance directly, you don't need a pseudo-rsquared

```
total_var <-svyvar(y, design)
resid_var <- summary(model)$dispersion
rsq <- 1-resid_var/total_var
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This should actually do the trick. However I'm actually getting really weird values out of this. I have very low coefficients (simple linear model with log transformed dependent variable and the coefficient is only 0.016750) but the r-squared calculated is 0.994. Any idea how this is possible?

Comment: Yeah, this gives really weird results, sometimes even less than 0.

Comment: @Moritary There's no way (without additional information) to relate the rsquared and the regression coefficient.

Comment: @dash2 this would be more helpful with an example

Comment: @ThomasLumley I will send you an example by email

Comment: Example sent to your wash u address

Comment: I haven't had access to that email address for about a decade -- the Maintainer address in the the survey package works.