# Add information in stargazer with coeftest

Tags: r, stargazer

I am estimating a model using survey design and robust errors, and I am trying to display the results with stargazer. However, I haven't been able to add basic information, such as number of observations, R2, Adjusted R2, Residual Std. Error and F Statistic, at the end of the table.

My code is something like this (I abbreviated the model):

```
# Svy design.
svy <- svydesign(id = ~conglomerado, 
                 strata = ~estrato, 
                 check.strata = TRUE,
                 weights = ~fact_cal_esi, 
                 data = subset(completos, ocup_ref==1))

# Estimation.
short_model <- svyglm(ln_w ~ sex + age + factor(level),
                      design=svy)
short_model_r <- coeftest(short_model , vcov = vcovHC(short_model , type = "HC1"))

# Table.
stargazer(models,type="text", 
          column.labels = c("Short model"),
          title = 'Table 1: Short model')
```

But I do not know how to add those statistics.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `svyglm` does not produce statistics like R-squared that can then be passed to `stargazer`. It seems that you would have to calculate these additional statistics of interest yourself and then pass them to `stargazer` using the `add.lines` parameter of `stargazer`. You can read about `add.lines` in the `stargazer` documentation here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf.

Here would be a reproducible example:

```
library(survey);library(stargazer)
set.seed(1)

data = data.frame(conglomerado=rnorm(100),
                  estrato=rnorm(100),
                  fact_cal_esi=abs(rnorm(100)),
                  sex=rnorm(100),
                  age=rnorm(100),
                  ln_w=rnorm(100),
                  level=rnorm(100))

# Svy design.
svy <- svydesign(id = ~conglomerado, 
                 strata = ~estrato, 
                 check.strata = TRUE,
                 weights = ~fact_cal_esi, 
                 data = data)

# Estimation.
options(survey.lonely.psu="remove")
short_model <- svyglm(ln_w ~ sex + age + factor(level),
                      design=svy)

#R-squared according to 
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73926485/survey-package-how-do-i-get-r-squared-from-a-svyglm-object
total_var <-svyvar(data, svy)
resid_var <- summary(short_model)$dispersion
rsq <- 1-resid_var/total_var

# Table.
stargazer(short_model,type="text", 
          column.labels = c("Short model"),
          title = 'Table 1: Short model',
          omit="level",
          add.lines = list(c("R-Squared","1")))
```

These other posts ask similar questions about calculating these statistics from `svyglm()` and may be helpful to you in doing this:

[Survey-package: How do I get R-squared from a svyglm-object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73926485/survey-package-how-do-i-get-r-squared-from-a-svyglm-object) ,

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/618248/how-to-calculate-f-statistic-from-a-svyglm-model-in-r ,

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/523152/different-ways-to-calculate-rsquared-after-regression-with-complex-survey-data-i.